# $\mathcal{L}_{I}^{C C} $ global $U(1)$ invariance

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, standard-model, neutrinos

It is well known that the SM lagrangian has the $U(1)$ symmetry. Considering for the moment the global symmetry $U(1)$, I am having some trouble seeing it in the following terms:

$$\mathcal{L}_{I}^{C C}=-\frac{g}{\sqrt{2}} \sum_{\ell=e, \mu, \tau}\left(W_{\mu}^{+} \bar{\nu}_{\ell L} \gamma^{\mu} \ell_{L}+W_{\mu}^{-} \bar{\ell}_{L} \gamma^{\mu} \nu_{\ell L}\right)$$

after the transformation I should obtain $\mathcal{L}^{'}=\mathcal{L}$:

$$\mathcal{L}_{I}^{C C}=-\frac{g}{\sqrt{2}} \sum_{\ell=e, \mu, \tau}\left(W_{\mu}^{+} \bar{\nu}_{\ell L} e^{i \alpha_l}\gamma^{\mu} \ell_{L}e^{-i \beta_l}+W_{\mu}^{-} \bar{\ell}_{L} e^{i \beta_l}\gamma^{\mu} \nu_{\ell L}e^{-i \alpha_l}\right).$$

This should implies that $\alpha_l=\beta_l$ which is not true, because we know that lepton are charged and neutrinos no.

---

In case of interaction lagrangian of QED as far as I know, you can see that it will conserve the electric charge doing:
$$\mathcal{L}_{I}^{',QED}=  - q_e \bar{\psi}e^{iq_e}{A\!\!\!/}e^{-iq_e}\psi=- q_e \bar{\psi}{A\!\!\!/}\psi =\mathcal{L}_{I}^{QED}$$

Honestly I have never transformed a gauge boson under a **global** symmetry, however, the only way in which the previous Lagrangian is invariant, according to a transformation that is connected to the electric charge, is :
$$\mathcal{L}_{I}^{',C C}=-\frac{g}{\sqrt{2}} \sum_{\ell=e, \mu, \tau}\left(W_{\mu}^{+} e^{-iq_W}\bar{\nu}_{\ell L} e^{iq_{\nu}}\gamma^{\mu} \ell_{L}e^{-iq_{\ell}}+W_{\mu}^{-}e^{iq_W} \bar{\ell}_{L} e^{iq_{l}}\gamma^{\mu} \nu_{\ell L}e^{-iq_{\nu}}\right)= \mathcal{L}_{I}^{C C}$$
with $q_w=e,q_{\ell}=-e,q_{\nu}=0$

maybe is correct in this way, but I'm not sure...

Comment: *Which* U(1) are you talking about? Weak hypercharge? (You did not transform the charged Ws.) Both charge and neutral leptons in a doublet have the *same* weak hypercharge. What *are* you talking about? Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, putting the hypercharge the two exponentials are the same and that is ok. What is not clear to me is the following, each term of the Lagrangian must conserve the **electric charge**, each conserved quantity corresponds to a symmetry. So I'm looking for the symmetry associated with the conservation of electric charge. I have never seen a vector boson transform with an exponential for a U(1) global symmetry. However, that term conserves the electric charge as the vector boson and the lepton always have opposite charges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cornerstone symmetry associated with the electric charge in the SM is, as your text details, I'm sure,
$$
Q=T_3+ \frac{Y_w}{2},
$$
where $Y_W$ is the weak hypercharge, and $T_3$ is the z-component of the weak isospin (the SU(2)).

The fields in your currents have eigenvalues $(t_3, y_w)$ under these,
$$
W^+: \qquad (1, 0)\qquad \leadsto q= 1\\
e: \qquad (-1/2, -1)\qquad \leadsto q= -1\\
\nu: \qquad (1/2, -1)\qquad \leadsto q= 0,
$$
and reversed for the conjugates.

Plugging these into your expression shows all *Q, Y<sub>W</sub>, T₃* balance to 0s.

Can you repeat this check for each and every term of the SM? Your text did it in a hyper efficient way, which you might have missed...

---

*A propos of your comment*: I'm a bit confused as to what your "doubt" could possibly be... As  demonstrated, the charge of $W^+$ is, indeed, 1, and that's why we label it that way. You added the charges of the term you have written correctly.

If, instead, mysteriously, you were concerned about the *local* charge *Q* invariance of your action, not of any relevance to the term you already wrote, you skipped the crucial gauge coupling of your SM-QED action, which I'm sure your text writes down and discusses in painful detail,
$$
-ie[ \partial_\mu A_\nu (W_\mu^+ W_\nu^- -W_\nu^+ W_\mu^- )  \\ + A_\nu(-W_\mu^+\partial_\nu W^-_\mu   +W_\mu^-\partial_\nu W^+_\mu +W_\mu^+\partial_\mu W^-_\nu - W_\mu^-\partial_\mu W^+_\mu )].
$$
The first term (upstairs) is separately gauge invariant, while the second term is the EM (*Q*) current coupling involved in the gauge invariance of the *W* kinetic terms!

Comment: thank you very much for your answer I changed the question a bit to point the doubt a little better.